# What are the inhabitants of OA?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Are there only a few Guardians and 3600 green lanterns living on OA? I remember that OA is almost fully industrialized on its planet's surface with countless high-tech buildings. A planet like this could have held a population of tens of billions, just like Coruscant in the Star Wars universe. Is there anyone else living on OA besides the Guardians and green lanterns?

Comment: They appear to have left the planet; https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3JjP.jpg - Per [The Green Lantern Corps #223](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern_Corps_Vol_1_223)

Comment: So OA is largely an abandoned planet and there are still a lot of (millions?billions?) Guardian's kins in the universe? @Valorum

Comment: It depends on which comics you read. In some OA is populated, plus there's a whole thing about the Oans returning to their planet; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Universe. I'll leave it for someone more  knowledgeable than I about the Green Lantern comics to write up a proper answer